# A different approach to add/remove classes and animate elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have 5 list items, when one is clicked the only method I know is to animate all the elements then reanimate the selected element to the new width. Can anyone advise me how I can cut down this process so only the current active item gets animated and the class removed and then the new item gets animated and the active class added?

JS

```
var test = $('#test'),
    test_li = test.children(),
    small = 60,
    large = 200;

test_li.on('click', function(e) {

    if( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){
        test_li.animate({ width: small }, 300).removeClass('active'); //animates every single li every time
        $(this).animate({ width: large }, 300).addClass('active');
    } 

});​
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/TSNtu/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var test = $('#test'),
    test_li = test.children(),
    small = 60,
    large = 200;

test_li.on('click', function(e) {

    // if clicked element is active itself then do nothing
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return;

    // remove active from others
    $('.active', test).animate({
        width: small
    }, 300).removeClass('active');
    // animate the clicked one
    $(this).animate({
        width: large
    }, 300).addClass('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TSNtu/10/)**

With a single chain

```
var test = $('#test'),
    test_li = test.children(),
    small = 60,
    large = 200;

test_li.on('click', function(e) {

    // if clicked element is active itself then do nothing
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return;

    $(this) // clicked li
        .animate({
            width: large
        }, 300)
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings('.active') // other li
        .animate({
            width: small
        }, 300)
        .removeClass('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TSNtu/11/)**

Comment: hey, this is great BUT this still animates all the list items when a click is fired? All items are animated to 60px while the newly active one is animated to 300px? Is there a way just to animate the selected item to large and the old active element to small?

Comment: I just updated that slightly to stop .active being reanimated if it is already open: http://jsfiddle.net/TSNtu/9/ maybe you would do this differently?